# Excel freeze pane acting up when using customviews and clearing filters

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I found a wonderful piece of code on here that lets me save all filter settings, clear them, do some code, then re-apply the filters using the customeview feature.  Here is my issue though, when I am done using the spreadsheet with the current filter, i clear that filter, then freeze pane is messed up and the whole window is frozen.  I have to go and click unfreeze panes to get it to scroll again, then redo where i wanted the pane to be frozen at.  Here is the code i am using:

```
Private Sub SaveAndClearFilters()
Latch = 0

If ws.AutoFilterMode = True And ws.FilterMode = True Then
    ThisWorkbook.CustomViews.ADD ViewName:="AutoFilterSettings", RowColSettings:=True
    ws.ShowAllData
    Latch = 1
End If

End Sub
```

Do some code, then

```
Private Sub RestoreFilters()
If Latch = 1 Then
    ThisWorkbook.CustomViews("AutoFilterSettings").Show
    ThisWorkbook.CustomViews("AutoFilterSettings").Delete
End If
End Sub
```

Then like i said when the user needs to clear the filter they are currently using, the freeze pane is messed up.  Any suggestions?

Additional Information Edit:
The sheet i am currently working in is 1,500 rows long roughly.  I have one column that has Xs in it, some rows have Xs, other do not.  When i filter to see rows with only Xs in them, then run my code, and then unfilter manually to see the whole sheet, the problem happens.  The freeze pane is originally set at row 6, when i filter the Xs, run the code, then the freeze pane is now on the first row that had Xs (row 395).  Its like the code is moving the freeze pane from row 6 to 395.

EDIT#2, it seems that the custom view isn't registering that the freeze is actually on row 6.  It is acting like when i take the snapshot it is on row 395 (which when the filter is on, it goes row 5 then row 395), then when i reapply the custom view it puts it there.... UGH.

EDIT#3, i thought i might record the freeze pane information, then reapply it last in the code to fix this.  Things get weirder... i tell it to split at row 5, it says it is split at row 5 but in reality it is still split at 395...!!

Here is the code i tried:

```
Private Sub SaveAndClearFilters()
Latch = 0

If ws.AutoFilterMode = True And ws.FilterMode = True Then
    ThisWorkbook.CustomViews.ADD ViewName:="AutoFilterSettings", RowColSettings:=True
    ws.ShowAllData
    FreezeColumn = ActiveWindow.SplitColumn
    FreezeRow = ActiveWindow.SplitRow
    Latch = 1
End If

End Sub

Private Sub RestoreFilters()

If Latch = 1 Then
    ThisWorkbook.CustomViews("AutoFilterSettings").Show
    ThisWorkbook.CustomViews("AutoFilterSettings").Delete
    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = FreezeColumn
        .SplitRow = FreezeRow
    End With
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
End If

End Sub
```

The freeze column seems to take, but the row will not.  If i do a msgbox on FreezeRow it says 5

Comment: reset the freeze panes in code?

Comment: do you mean reset to a hard coded freeze?  or is there a way to save it and reapply?  I would like the user to be able to keep whatever freeze they feel is most helpful to them.  I'm really not even sure why this code changes the freeze pane location at all in the first place.

Comment: Could be that the freeze is on filtered data, so when you unfilter it the freeze stays on the row, but that row is lower now (in screen view) so it appears to be "broken", but in reality its still the same. Just guessing. Maybe you can also capture freeze pane settings and restore?

Comment: When i was troubleshooting it i looked into that and repeated the problem a few times.  I have no filters on, then i freeze row 6.  I then manually filter out blanks on the one column that has the Xs in it.  Then i run my code above.  Then I manually unfilter the column to show blanks and Xs.  Freeze is now on row 395... :(  The thing is im sure the custom view does capture the freeze pane, but it should be putting it right back to where it was.

Comment: Maybe there is another way to save the filter settings instead of using customview which seems to be saving more than i want?